# questions on GO space

Tags: general-topology

There is a proposition from the paper: A broader context for monotonically monolithic spaces.[image]

I have several questions:

Q1, Does every GO-space have $\chi(X)\le c(X)$?

Q2, why $d(X)\le \omega_1$?

Q3, why the author said, $\{X\setminus F_\alpha: \alpha < \omega_1\}$ is point-countable and uncountable which is a tradiction?

If you can answer one question of these, I will also vote you. Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\cl}{\operatorname{cl}}$Let $\langle X,\le,\tau\rangle$ be a GO-space.

- If $x\in\cl(\leftarrow,x)$, let $\langle x_\xi:\xi<\kappa\rangle$ be a strictly increasing sequence in $(\leftarrow,x)$ converging to $x$, where $\kappa$ is the cofinality of the order $\big\langle(\leftarrow,x),\le\big\rangle$; we may assume without loss of generality that $(x_\xi,x_{\xi+1})\ne\varnothing$ for each $\xi<\kappa$. Otherwise let $\kappa=\omega$, and let $x_n=x$ for each $n\in\omega$.
- Similarly, if $x\in\cl(x,\to)$, let $\langle y_\xi:\xi<\lambda\rangle$ be a strictly decreasing sequence in $(x,\to)$ converging to $x$, where $\lambda$ is the cofinality of $\big\langle(x,\to),\ge\big\rangle$; we may further assume that $(y_{\xi+1},y_\xi)\ne\varnothing$ for each $\xi<\lambda$. Otherwise let $\lambda=\omega$, and let $y_n=x$ for $n\in\omega$.

Then $\{(x_\xi,y_\eta):\xi<\kappa\text{ and }\eta<\lambda\}$ is a nbhd base at $x$ of cardinality $\chi(x,X)=\max\{\kappa,\lambda\}$. If $x$ is isolated, then $\chi(x,X)=\omega\le c(X)$, so assume that $x$ is not isolated. Without loss of generality $x\in\cl(\leftarrow,x)$ and $\chi(x,X)=\kappa\ge\lambda$. But then $\left\{(x_\xi,x_{\xi+1}):\xi<\kappa\right\}$ is a family of $\kappa$ pairwise disjoint, non-empty open subsets of $X$, so $\chi(x,X)=\kappa\le c(X)$. It follows that $\chi(X)\le c(X)$.

Being a GO-space, $X$ is a dense subspace of some LOTS $Y$, and it’s easy to see that $c(X)\ge c(Y)$. Theorem $2.8$ of István Juhász, *Cardinal Functions in Topology* (available from the link in reference $[2]$ [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_function#References)) says that if $Y$ is a LOTS, then $hd(Y)=d(Y)\le c(Y)^+$, so $d(X)\le c(Y)^+\le c(X)^+$.

(The answer to the first question is mentioned in a note in Juhász, but the argument isn’t actually given.)

Henno has answered the third question, but I think that there’s a slightly easier way to look at it that doesn’t involve explicit mention of point-countability at all. Since $\mathscr{F}$ is an increasing chain of closed sets whose union is $X$, the family $\mathscr{U}=\{X\setminus F_\alpha:\alpha<\omega_1\}$ is a decreasing chain of open sets with empty intersection. We’re assuming that no $F_\alpha=X$, so the sets $X\setminus F_\alpha$ are all non-empty. $X$ has calibre $\omega_1$, so there is an uncountable $\Lambda\subseteq\omega_1$ such that $\bigcap_{\alpha\in\Lambda}(X\setminus F_\alpha)\ne\varnothing$. But $\mathscr{U}$ is a chain, and $\Lambda$ is cofinal in $\omega_1$, so $\bigcap\mathscr{U}=\bigcap_{\alpha\in\Lambda}(X\setminus F_\alpha)\ne\varnothing$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: I realised the chain argument, but I meant to stick as closely as I could to the paper's argument.

Comment: @Henno: I suspected as much, but I thought it worth having both available.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: From the proposition, it seems that every space $X$ has caribre-$\omega_1$ and $d(X)=\omega_1$, then the space is separable. Is it right?

Comment: @Paul: I think you meant $d(X)\le\omega_1$; yes, if $d(X)\le\omega_1$ and $X$ has calibre $\omega_1$, then this argument shows that $d(X)=\omega$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Thanks.

Comment: @Paul: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 2):

See Juhasz' "cardinal functions in topology", where it is shown that for linearly ordered spaces (and hence for GO-spaces as well, as these are subspaces of ordered spaces) $\chi(X) \le c(X)$
and $c(X) \le d(X) \le c(X)^{+}$ (around page 18).

So this answers the first 2: these are standard cardinal function facts.

The last follows from $X$ having calibre $\omega_1$, which means that any uncountable family of non-empty open subsets of $X$ there is an uncountable subfamily with non-empty intersection. The stated family is such a family of non-empty open subsets, but as it is point countable (every point is in at most countably many members) **every** uncountable subfamily has empty intersection. So this contradicts the calibre $\omega_1$ property.

Comment: Juhász doesn’t actually give the argument for $\chi(X)\le c(X)$; he just mentions that Nelly Kroonenberg showed it. Cellularity and density aren’t hereditary, so the fact that $d(x)\le c(X)^+$ for a LOTS $X$ doesn’t immediately generalize to GO-spaces; some argument is needed.

Comment: $c(X) = hl(X)$ for GO-spaces (also for monotonically normal spaces), and $d(X) = hd(X)$ as well for such spaces. So in GO space they are hereditary. But I agree some argument is needed. I'm not sure whether $d(X) \le c(X)^{+}$ generalizes to MN spaces.